# MinimizeRestore Maximize boxes missing in Windows 10 task bar

Tags: qgis, windows-10

I am running QGIS 2.18.15 on a Windows 10 OS 64-bit PC and the click symbols to close (x), minimize, restore, maximize are missing. I tried uninstalling and reloading the latest version and had same problem. I can use the keystroke commands but it is impossible to resize the window that way. In order to move the QGIS window between screens I must also use the keystroke commands - cannot drag between screens.

Everything else seems to work fine.

Am just wondering if this is a common problem and if there is a fix.

Answer (score 5):

Click `F11` or go to menu `view / toggle full screen mode`

Comment: Wow was looking into windows problems but the fix was this simple. thanks dude